# How can I make image in text box with no-repeat

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, background-repeat

I am applying an image to a text box as follows

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Style="background-image: url('Popup(Images)/Solved.png');"
        BorderStyle="None"  />
```

This is giving the following result

[image]

I tried it applying no-repeat but the image is not getting displayed. can any one help me. Why  I am using Text box is the only control which gray out when its property set to `disabled` or if any one having any idea how to gray out `image button` with displaying image give me that solution

Comment: use background-repeat:no-repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input.textbox
{
   background-image: url('Popup(Images)/Solved.png');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" BorderStyle="None"  />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Style="background: #ffffff url('Popup(Images)/Solved.png') no-repeat center center;" BorderStyle="None"  />
```

When using the shorthand property the order of the property values are:

- background-color
- background-image
- background-repeat
- background-attachment
- background-position

Comment: Image not getting displayed if i do like this

Comment: What is the Popup(...)? I think you want url(Images/Solved.png).

Comment: That's the folder which holds images

Comment: Your folder is named Popop(Images) or just Images?

Comment: `Popop(Images)` is my folder name

Answer (score 2):

> or if any one having any idea how to gray out image button with displaying image give me that solution

You can use a custom style to a disabled input type, as shown in this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/964dL/4/

Answer (score 0):

give `background-repeat` property in style of your textbox

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

`style="background: #fff url(images/solved.png) no-repeat 0px 5px;"`